# How to change Safari's default HTTP concurrent max download setting's?

Tags: http, safari

I am currently reading a javascript book. It says that browser's have a user setting for HTTP request limit that can be changed from the default of 2 simultaneous downloads to whatever you'd like.

I have looked in the Safari --> Preferences settings to try and find this setting to no avail.

Whats the deal?

Comment: Safari already has a default of 4 simultaneous downloads per host, so the book's wrong about that. Are you sure this is actually a problem?

Comment: Its not a problem. But I want to learn the intricacies of the settings and experiment with the performance gain or loss.  How do you access them?